# AttributeError: 'BoxesView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Trying to add a form to my homepage view and getting this error when I submit the form. Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'polls.html'
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')
        return self.form_invalid(form) 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()

        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        choice = Choice.objects.all()
        context['question_list'] = question_list
        context['choice'] = choice

        q_list = []
        returned_list = []

        for i in question_list:
            q_list.append(i)

        for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
            name = resolve(self.request.path_info).url_name
            if b == name:
                category = a

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')
        if search:
            posts = posts.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(content__icontains=search)
            )        
        else:
            posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

        context['posts'] = posts

        total = 0
        for post in posts:
            returned_list.append(post)
            total += 1
            if total == 4:
                total = 0
                for i in q_list:
                    returned_list.append(i)
                    q_list.remove(i)
                    break

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')
        if search:
            posts = posts.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(content__icontains=search)
            )
        else:
            posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

        context['posts'] = posts

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]
```

**base.html**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="registerBox">
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

My traceback is pointing me to these lines: `return self.form_invalid(form)` & `context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()`. Hopefully this can give you an indication of what the problem is but i've been unable to work it out.Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I manage a solution, if you don't have the `user_list` variable in your class you have to put it in, but it's better overriding the constructor, but tou neetd to put the model variable in your class.

```
class BoxesView(ListView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'polls.html'
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    model = YourModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxesView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

It's usefull :P

Comment: I realized when I submit the form the object_list returns the objects.all() exepring the first element, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ListView, either you should `specify a model attribute` with

```
class BoxesView(ListView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'polls.html'
    model = yourModel
```

or you should specify queryset in get_queryset method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = yourModel.objects.all()
    return qs
```

Note that `queryset is accessed in templates by the default name object_list`.

Also rather than creating objects using forms in ListView, try only to list objects in ListView. `Use CreateView to create objects`. Your ListView may look like the below.

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'
    model = yourModel
    paginate_by = 20
```

Refer to [this link](http://ccbv.co.uk/) for more details

Also from your question it seems like you are trying to iterate over Post objects which are passed to template as context data. Note that `Overriding def get_context_data(self) is to provide extra context variables`, not queryset and ListView always expect model or get_queryset(self) to be defined in your class inherited from ListView. If what you are trying to do is to create a ListView for Post objects, try setting `model=Post` in your class.

Comment: Why do I need to specifiy get_queryset() when i've already passed through the queryset as context? (`context['posts'] = posts`). Also when you said to use CreateView to create objects did you mean to create my form? so don't include the form in my ListView?

Comment: Also I just added in: `qs = yourModel.objects.all()
    return qs` to my get_queryset() method and i'm getting the same error.

Comment: The reason I'm using `get_context_data()` to return the queryset is because i'm not actually returning just the queryset - I'm returning a list I built which comprises of 2 querysets (Post & Question). Because of this, should I build this list in `get_context_data()` like I currently am or should I build it in `get_queryset()`?

Comment: Yep so i've done that now - however i'm still getting the original `AttributeError: 'BoxesView' object has no attribute 'object_list'`. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Try specifying model in your class or try to override `get_queryset(self)` and then return model objects from get_queryset.

Comment: I have the same problem now in 2020